# ¿Por que no puedo entrenar mi modelo?

Tags: machine-learning, redes-neuronales

Estoy intentando hacer un algoritmo de clasificación con CNN 1D, sin embargo, al ingresar mis datos de entrada para entrenamiento con sus respectivas etiquetas me aparece el siguiente error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Sin embargo, mis datos de entrenamiento los estoy guardando como tipo float dentro de un arreglo NumPy.

Answer (score 0):

El error te indica que estás intentado convertir un `None` a entero.

`None` significa que en vez de estar pasando datos, **estás pasando una variable vacía** en algún sitio. Exactamente el error que tu tienes, aparece al hacer esto:

```
print(int(None))

Out:
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```